# Compiling a simple Gsoap Service

Tags: c++, web-services, compilation, gsoap

I'm very new to gsoap and am attempting to follow this example.

[Gsoap Example](http://www.genivia.com/products/gsoap/demos/calc.html)

I successfully installed Gsoap by downloading the binaries and using the following commands:

./configure --disable-ssl, make, sudo make install

I then created my .h file as shown in the example and compiled it using soapcpp2.
I created a .cpp file as the example shows and attempted to compile.

**When compiling, I am receiving compile errors in my automatically generated soapC.cpp class as well as my auto generated soapServer.cpp class.  There are multiple errors and they are all approximately the same.**

> soapServer.cpp: undefined reference to 'ns_sub(soap*, double, double
>   ,double*)'

I'm sure that this is a linker error.  I am linking to the gsoap++ library that was created during the make process.  Does anybody have any ideas?  Thanks!

Ps.  Here is the command that is being issued by eclipse:

> g++ -o "GsoapTest" ./src/GsoapTest.o ./src/soapC.0 ./src/soapServer.o
>   ./src/soapServerLib.o  -lgsoap++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you have specified the service operation `ns__sub` correctly in step 1 of the example? The generated `soapServer.cpp` does not find a reference to `ns_sub` with one `_` but I guess you have implemented it as in step 2 (`ns__sub`, with a double underscore).